# Compensando a perda do Select Option

Tags: css, css3

Tenho um estilo que uso para os campos do **formulário**:

```
.inputTextMedio {
    border: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

O problema é que estou usando também para os `Select Options`.

No entando, os `Select Options` acabam ***comendo os pixels*** do `margin` e `padding` e, no final, ao invés de ficarem com

```
width: 250px;
height: 30px;
```

Eles acabam ficando com

```
width: 242px; + 6 do padding + 2 do border = 250
height: 22px; + 6 do padding + 2 do border = 30
```

Existe uma forma de compensar essa perda?

Por exemplo:

```
select {
  width  += 8px;
  height += 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> O elemento `select` tem por padrão `box-sizing: border-box;`. Basta
>   alterar para `content-box`.

Crie mais um estilo apenas para o select e coloque `box-sizing: content-box;`:

```
select.inputTextMedio{
   box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

**Exemplo sem:**

```css
.inputTextMedio {
    border: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<input class="inputTextMedio">
<br>
<select class="inputTextMedio">
   <option> Selecione</option>
</select>
```

**Exemplo com:**

```css
.inputTextMedio {
    border: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
}

select.inputTextMedio{
   box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

```html
<input class="inputTextMedio">
<br>
<select class="inputTextMedio">
   <option> Selecione</option>
</select>
```

Comment: obrigado, era isso mesmo!

Comment: Realmente o border-box "não funcionou" como o esperado! Boa dica tio!

Answer (score 2):

Vc pode usar a função cal do CSS para compensar isso.

Então se está assim:

```
width: 242px; + 6 do padding + 2 do border = 250
height: 22px; + 6 do padding + 2 do border = 30
```

Ficaria assim:

```
width: calc(242px + 8px); 
height: calc(22px + 8px);
```

**Dica:** Aqui vc pode ler mais sobre o calc() do css: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Comment: no caso do calc não funciona pois o width e heght estou pegando de uma classe de estilo 
Mas o box-sizing: content-box; deu certo

Comment: @CarlosRocha legal, então crédito para o Sam que deu a dica ;)

Comment: blz, já dei o crédito para ele